# Use GIMP to resize image in one layer only

Tags: image, resize, layer, gimp

This is my set up. I have 2 layers with transparency (I don't know if transparency matters here). Layers are the same size, 5x7 inches. Each layer has their image (say I draw a square on it and a circle on the other).

I want to resize ONLY the square.

The problem is when I scale the square I end up either scaling both, the circle AND the square, equally and they retain their layer size, or BOTH layers are rezise and no longer 5x7 inches. I've tried 'Tools-Transform-Scale' and 'Image-Resize canvas or image', but I can't find the tool to just resize ONE of the images.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the Scale tool, and it will resize only the active layer if it is in `Scale: layer` mode (you seem to have it in `Scale: image` mode)(*).

[image]

[image]

Otherwise, to clear up things:

- `Image > Canvas size` changes the size of the canvas, but nothing is stretched/compressed, the layers retain their size or are extended with transparency or white.
- `Image > Scale image` scales everything in the image (layers, channels, paths...)

(*) Also,if what you apply a transform such as Scale to an item that has the chainlink, the same transform will be applied to all other chainlinked items (other layers, but also paths).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I had tried this, but now it works. It scales down only the selected layer so I realized that after I failed the first time (probably because it was in image mode) I started clicking things and I activated these two things that look like chain links on my layers panel and when they are activated they make the same change on the other layer; howevever it doesn't only scale down the image, but the layers themself shrink as well from 5 to 3 inches.

Comment: I mentioned chain links in my first version but removed it to make thing simple. Since you mention them, I have added them back.

Comment: To add to this, if you're wondering where the scale tool is in Gimp 2.10+ it has been moved into an icon called 'Unified Transform Tool' in the toolbar. Right click the icon to select the scale tool from the dropdown.